# Javascript seems not to be working on mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, toggle

I have a text toggle option on my (WordPress) website:

If you click on the red "info" link on the right the text under it opens. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work on mobile (iPhone 4). See the screenshot attached. It seems to me the javascript is not loading at all or just not working?

html link:

```
<div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="projectTitel">
    <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><button rel="bookmark" class="show">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '<div class="info">Info &#8595;</div><div class="close_info">X</div></button></h2>' ); ?>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("projectTitel");

[...divs].forEach(someDiv => someDiv.addEventListener("click", handler));

// by default, all Inhoud divs are hidden
hideElements("Inhoud");
hideElements("close_info");
jQuery('.info').show();

function handler(event) {
    // get the clicked project's index :
    var projectIndex = getClickedProjectIndex(event);

    // toggle the right Inhoud div :
    toggleDiv(document.getElementsByClassName("Inhoud")[projectIndex]);
        toggleDiv(document.getElementsByClassName("close_info")[projectIndex]);
        toggleDiv(document.getElementsByClassName("info")[projectIndex]);
}

// hide all elements that have the provided class name
function hideElements(className) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    [...elements].forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
}

function getClickedProjectIndex(event) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("projectTitel");
    var projectIndex = 0;

    [...elements].forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.id == event.currentTarget.id) {
            projectIndex = index;
        }
    });

    return projectIndex;
}

function toggleDiv(element) {

   if (element.style.display === 'none') {
      element.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
</script>
```

[image: website on mobile]

Comment: Please add relevant code here as a [mcve], not links to off-site resources.

Comment: I found this erorr in Safari: 

TypeError: undefined is not a function

About the following line:

    [...divs].forEach(someDiv => someDiv.addEventListener("click", handler));

Answer (score 0):

Replace "[...divs]" on "Array.from(divs)"

And do it for all other instances of [...{a}].